# clip polygon by polyline in r sf

Tags: r, r-sf

Is there a way to clip the outside area of a polygon by a polyline that runs through the polygon?
The image below shows the area that I'd like to clip out in yellow.[image: clip]

Below is my code to create the objects. Right now, I've only used the sf package, but i am open to  any suggested solutions.

```
red_line<- structure(list(OBJECTID = "15176", SENSE = "D2E", FAULT = "A", 
    geometry = structure(list(structure(c(153933.271600001, 153933.2116, 
    153945.4649, 153957.4899, 153966.033, 153943.068499999, 153897.4023, 
    153895.038799999, 153888.507099999, 153873.434699999, 153836.0955, 
    153792.7015, 153778.984999999, 153772.0712, 153718.213099999, 
    153728.529300001, 153700.3364, 153710.089199999, 153726.623299999, 
    153702.5626, 153715.2884, 153679.427100001, 153703.297700001, 
    153658.0449, 153648.3902, 153601.6642, 153566.573100001, 
    153546.759400001, 153494.6261, 153482.0064, 153425.1044, 
    153375.324100001, 2279628.4984, 2279628.0437, 2279365.0716, 
    2279257.8252, 2279113.9782, 2278941.4251, 2278721.8255, 2278589.1488, 
    2278497.253, 2278370.9308, 2278189.5671, 2278138.9428, 2278046.1624, 
    2277948.9991, 2277819.6521, 2277746.59, 2277646.0458, 2277515.1394, 
    2277437.0593, 2277324.7811, 2277232.3925, 2277145.4616, 2277028.2828, 
    2276926.7065, 2276802.7129, 2276725.6093, 2276600.081, 2276500.0358, 
    2276373.1791, 2276298.4293, 2276245.5729, 2276136.53), dim = c(32L, 
    2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 153375.324100001, 
    ymin = 2276136.53, xmax = 153966.033, ymax = 2279628.4984
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "NAD83 / Alaska Albers", 
        wkt = "PROJCRS[\"NAD83 / Alaska Albers\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n        DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4269]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Alaska Albers (meters)\",\n        METHOD[\"Albers Equal Area\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",50,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",-154,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",55,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",65,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Topographic mapping (small scale).\"],\n        AREA[\"United States (USA) - Alaska.\"],\n        BBOX[51.3,172.42,71.4,-129.99]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",3338]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = 1L, class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(OBJECTID = NA_integer_, 
SENSE = NA_integer_, FAULT = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))

blue_buffer<-structure(list(OBJECTID = "203", SAND = "A", output = 2L, geometry = structure(list(
    structure(list(structure(c(155608.591046923, 155592.009898102, 
    155580.434598297, 155564.159138503, 155488.752738503, 155471.735621873, 
    155451.57675253, 155428.331384533, 155402.063231819, 155372.84429357, 
    155340.754656863, 155305.882277164, 155268.32273724, 155228.178985181, 
    155185.561052219, 155140.585751146, 155093.376356138, 155044.062264864, 
    154992.77864382, 154939.666057847, 154884.870084852, 154828.540916787, 
    154770.832947987, 154711.904351983, 154651.916647961, 154591.034258048, 
    154529.424056642, 154467.254913023, 154404.697228493, 154341.922469316, 
    154279.102696744, 154216.410095407, 154154.016501368, 154092.092931131, 
    154030.809112897, 153970.333021353, 153910.830417262, 153852.464393125, 
    153795.394926159, 153739.778439804, 153685.767374985, 153633.509772276, 
    153583.148866133, 153534.822692299, 153488.663709459, 153444.798436175, 
    153403.347104112, 153364.423328491, 153328.133796674, 153294.577975747, 
    153263.847839881, 153236.027618243, 153211.193564128, 153189.41374595, 
    153170.747860678, 153155.247070206, 153142.953861124, 153133.901928261, 
    153128.116082339, 153125.612181957, 153126.397090133, 153130.468655489, 
    153137.815718146, 153148.418140316, 153162.246861497, 153219.023030085, 
    153221.055613674, 153220.508542894, 153210.172720066, 153204.146964349, 
    153201.214351913, 153201.382462385, 153204.650861267, 153211.011101057, 
    153220.446743081, 153232.933399981, 153248.438798748, 153266.922864134, 
    153302.641664134, 153324.555253228, 153349.469635205, 153377.317581449, 
    153408.02394746, 153441.505875619, 153477.673018766, 153516.427783999, 
    153557.665596012, 153601.275179281, 153647.138858327, 153695.132875254, 
    153745.127723689, 153796.988498248, 153850.575258554, 153905.743406858, 
    153962.344078215, 154020.22454218, 154079.228614935, 154139.197080731, 
    154199.968121513, 154261.377753574, 154323.260270036, 154385.448687999, 
    154447.775199123, 154510.071622439, 154572.169858166, 154633.902341311, 
    154705.340041311, 154767.137711587, 154828.222509459, 154888.426353685, 
    154947.583587058, 155005.531432233, 155062.110439621, 155117.164926136, 
    155170.543403572, 155222.098995435, 155271.689841096, 155319.17948613, 
    155364.437257787, 155407.338624549, 155447.765538797, 155485.606761626, 
    155520.758168934, 155553.123037928, 155582.61231327, 155609.144852117, 
    155632.647647401, 155653.056028709, 155670.313840235, 155684.373595297, 
    155695.196606999, 155702.753094689, 155707.022265895, 155710.991065895, 
    155711.962489984, 155709.644986361, 155704.044907143, 155695.177601757, 
    155683.067374872, 155667.747419778, 155649.259727406, 155627.654971237, 
    155608.591046923, 2276709.29938916, 2276573.88643007, 2276499.02593186, 
    2276425.0449129, 2276127.3880129, 2276066.91192135, 2276007.40931726, 
    2275949.04329312, 2275891.97382616, 2275836.3573398, 2275782.34627499, 
    2275730.08867228, 2275679.72776613, 2275631.4015923, 2275585.24260946, 
    2275541.37733617, 2275499.92600411, 2275461.00222849, 2275424.71269667, 
    2275391.15687575, 2275360.42673988, 2275332.60651824, 2275307.77246413, 
    2275285.99264595, 2275267.32676068, 2275251.82597021, 2275239.53276112, 
    2275230.48082826, 2275224.69498234, 2275222.19108196, 2275222.97599013, 
    2275227.04755549, 2275234.39461815, 2275244.99704032, 2275258.8257615, 
    2275275.84287813, 2275296.00174747, 2275319.24711547, 2275345.51526818, 
    2275374.73420643, 2275406.82384314, 2275441.69622284, 2275479.25576276, 
    2275519.39951482, 2275562.01744778, 2275606.99274885, 2275654.20214386, 
    2275703.51623514, 2275754.79985618, 2275807.91244215, 2275862.70841515, 
    2275919.03758321, 2275976.74555201, 2276035.67414802, 2276095.66185204, 
    2276156.54424195, 2276218.15444336, 2276280.32358698, 2276342.88127151, 
    2276405.65603068, 2276468.47580326, 2276531.16840459, 2276593.56199863, 
    2276655.48556887, 2276716.7693871, 2276940.88588565, 2276957.48534816, 
    2276968.42678442, 2277051.11304152, 2277111.82147428, 2277172.75769769, 
    2277233.76421602, 2277294.68335183, 2277355.35765355, 2277415.6303024, 
    2277475.34551771, 2277534.34895955, 2277592.48812764, 2277695.67572764, 
    2277754.03213333, 2277811.17186593, 2277866.94074042, 2277921.18827085, 
    2277973.76807647, 2278024.53827667, 2278073.36187387, 2278120.10712317, 
    2278164.64788785, 2278206.86397976, 2278246.64148359, 2278283.87306429, 
    2278318.4582567, 2278350.30373662, 2278379.32357267, 2278405.43945814, 
    2278428.58092229, 2278448.68552052, 2278465.69900287, 2278479.57546041, 
    2278490.2774491, 2278497.77609085, 2278502.05115142, 2278503.09109506, 
    2278500.8931156, 2278495.46314403, 2278486.81583251, 2278474.90963251, 
    2278462.93635715, 2278447.73902701, 2278429.35945914, 2278407.84822687, 
    2278383.2645206, 2278355.67598498, 2278325.15853278, 2278291.79613597, 
    2278255.68059468, 2278216.91128464, 2278175.59488368, 2278131.8450782, 
    2278085.78225041, 2278037.53314701, 2277987.23053048, 2277935.01281377, 
    2277881.02367941, 2277825.41168417, 2277768.32985031, 2277709.93524449, 
    2277650.38854562, 2277589.85360269, 2277528.49698396, 2277466.48751862, 
    2277403.99583222, 2277341.19387722, 2277245.94367722, 2277183.12651204, 
    2277120.34459518, 2277057.77000753, 2276995.57426168, 2276933.92783185, 
    2276872.9996866, 2276812.95682577, 2276753.96382264, 2276709.29938916
    ), dim = c(143L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, precision = 0, crs = structure(list(
    input = "NAD83 / Alaska Albers", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"NAD83 / Alaska Albers\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n        DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4269]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Alaska Albers (meters)\",\n        METHOD[\"Albers Equal Area\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",50,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",-154,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",55,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",65,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Topographic mapping (small scale).\"],\n        AREA[\"United States (USA) - Alaska.\"],\n        BBOX[51.3,172.42,71.4,-129.99]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",3338]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
"sfc"), bbox = structure(c(xmin = 153125.612181957, ymin = 2275222.19108196, 
xmax = 155711.962489984, ymax = 2278503.09109506), class = "bbox"))), row.names = 1L, sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(OBJECTID = NA_integer_, 
SAND = NA_integer_, output = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

black_line<- structure(list(OBJECTID = "203", SAND = "A", output = 2L, geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(154512.0314, 154508.0626, 154436.6249, 154400.9061, 
    154416.7812, 154424.7187, 154400.9062, 154325.4998, 2277195.9865, 
    2277291.2367, 2277303.1429, 2277199.9553, 2277072.955, 2276914.2047, 
    2276719.7356, 2276422.0787), dim = c(8L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
    "LINESTRING", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", "sfc"
), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 154325.4998, ymin = 2276422.0787, 
xmax = 154512.0314, ymax = 2277303.1429), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    input = "NAD83 / Alaska Albers", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"NAD83 / Alaska Albers\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n        DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4269]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Alaska Albers (meters)\",\n        METHOD[\"Albers Equal Area\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",50,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",-154,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",55,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",65,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Topographic mapping (small scale).\"],\n        AREA[\"United States (USA) - Alaska.\"],\n        BBOX[51.3,172.42,71.4,-129.99]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",3338]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = 1L, class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(OBJECTID = NA_integer_, 
SAND = NA_integer_, output = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Comment: This question seems to be very close to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426506/clipping-polygon-based-on-a-line-to-get-a-polygon-in-r/ which has been answered on our sister site / technically not a duplicity, since it is a different site, but still...

Comment: that does appear to answer my question, thanks!

Comment: glad to be of service :)